# avoid multiple pipes broken due to missing command

Tags: shell-script, pipe, portability

In shell scripts I often use multiple pipes like this:

```
cmd1 | cmd2 | cmd3
```

Now if `cmd2` is missing the pipe will result "broken" and `cmd3` won't receive any input.

As workaround I could test explicitly if cmd2 exist, but this requires some code replication I'd like to avoid.

Instead I'd like a more concise test like this:

```
cmd1 | cmd2; [ $? -eq 127 ] && cat | cmd3
```

Comment: the above test does not work, any alternative?

Comment: You can use `{` and `}` for grouping. E.g. `cmd1 | { which cmd2 >/dev/null && cmd2 || cat; } | cmd3` should have the desired effect. Are you looking for a way to forward the output of `cmd1` that has already been consumed by `cmd2` to `cmd3` if `cmd2` fails at any point? If so, you're probably better off writing to a temporary file.

Comment: Why not just test for the existence of `cmd2` before you even run the pipeline?

Comment: @GregoryNisbet, would you like to add that as an answer?  It's what I was going to suggest next, so I will post it as answer if you don't.  ;)

Comment: Related: [How to test if a command is installed?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/273955/135943)

Comment: @GregoryNisbet: `cmd2` cannot fail, i just want to handle the case it does not exist. Is it ok if i use a subshell instead? (slightly more concise): `cmd1 | ( cmd2; [ $? -eq 127 ] && cat ) | cmd3`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your example it looks like you're looking for a way to group arguments to operations with lower precedence than `|`, (i.e. `&&` and `||`).

The `{` and `}` metacharacters can be used for grouping in this way.

Your example above could be written like this (using the exit status of `which` to determine whether `cmd2` exists or not).

```
cmd1 | { which cmd2 >/dev/null && cmd2 || cat; } | cmd3
```

For example

```
printf "hi\n" | { : && rev || cat; } | cat
```

Will print `ih`

Your suggestion of using a subshell will also work, but uses another process unnecessarily

```
printf "hi\n" | ( : && rev || cat ) | cat
```

I would say it is probably less tricky and better for maintainability if you use an explicit `if` outside the pipe.

```
if [ which cmd2 >/dev/null ]
then
    cmd1 | cmd3
else
    cmd1 | cmd2 | cmd3
fi
```

Comment: as i've said i'd like to avoid an explicit test because cmd1,2,3,etc. may not be simple commands and i may need to test more than one. Also you need to provide the different pipelines for each case (code duplication).

Comment: @eadmaster In that case using something like \@meuh's answer and having an explicit function for each potential step in your process might make sense if you want to avoid temporary files. What is the processing you're actually trying to do? It might be cleaner to process a line at a time in a python/perl/awk script.

Comment: no, i think it is fine with command grouping so i can easily provide alternatives like this: `cmd1 | { alt1 || alt2 || cat ; } | cmd3`. The only thing i don't get in your answer is the `: &&` at the beginning of each group.

Comment: `:` is a shell builtin that just exits 0. Your suggestion `cmd1 | { alt1 || alt2 ; } | cmd3` will also work.

Answer (score 4):

You can write a mini function to make it more concise:

```
ifexists(){
    if command -v "$1"
    then "$@"
    else echo "doing cat for missing $1" >&2
         cat
    fi
}

echo hi | ifexists mycommand | cat -n
```